# How to make login signup with firebase phone number and password in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a challenge with flutter firebase I want to make login signup using phone number and password. I will take phone number and password at the time of signing up and same for login the otp will after successfully matched password but I am struggling to create it. I have done simple login signup using phone number but with password its not happening any lead on how I can do it in flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can allow your users to sign into your application using multiple providers by linking authentication credentials to existing user accounts. Users can then be identified using their Firebase UID, regardless of the provider they used to sign in